# Add a subtotal column for aggregated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, window-functions

Here's my dataset of trades, traders and counterparties:

```
TRADER_ID  | TRADER_NAME     | EXEC_BROKER | TRADE_AMOUNT  | TRADE_ID
    ABC123 | Jules Winnfield | GOLD        | 10000         | ASDADAD
    XDA241 | Jimmie Dimmick  | GOLD        | 12000         | ASSVASD
    ADC123 | Vincent Vega    | BARC        | 10000         | ZXCZCX
    ABC123 | Jules Winnfield | BARC        | 15000         | ASSXCQA
    ADC123 | Vincent Vega    | CRED        | 250000        | RFAQQA
    ABC123 | Jules Winnfield | CRED        | 5000          | ASDQ23A
    ABC123 | Jules Winnfield | GOLD        | 5000          | AVBDQ3A
```

I'm looking to produce a repeatable monthly report that gives me a view of trading activity aggregated at the counterparty (the EXEC_BROKER field) level, with subtotals - as shown below:

```
TRADER_ID | TRADER_NAME | NO._OF_CCP_USED | CCP | TRADED_AMT_WITH_CCP | VALUE_OF_TOTAL_TRADES | TRADES_WITH_CCP | TOTAL_TRADES
    ABC123 | Jules Winnfield | 3 | GOLD | 15000 | 35000 | 2 | 4
    ABC123 | Jules Winnfield | 3 | BARC | 15000 | 35000 | 1 | 4
    ABC123 | Jules Winnfield | 3 | CRED | 5000 | 35000 | 1 | 4
```

...and so on the rest.

The idea is to aggregate the number of trades per counterparty (which I have done using a count function), and the sum of traded amounts with the ccp, but I'm struggling to get the 'subtotal' field next to each trader as shown in my desired output above - so you can see here that Jules has dealt with 3 counterparties in total, with 4 trades between them, and a collective amount of 35000.

I have tried using a combination of aggregate and over by functions, but to no avail.

```
SELECT
     OT.TRADER_ID,
     OT.TRADER_NAME,
     OT.EXEC_BROKER,
     SUM(OT.TRADE_AMOUNT) AS VALUE_OF_TOTAL_TRADES,
     COUNT(OT.TRADE_ID) AS TOTAL_TRADES,
     COUNT(OT.EXEC_BROKER) OVER PARTITION BY (OT.TRADER_ID) AS NO._OF_CCP_USED, 
     SUM(OT.TRADE_AMOUNT) OVER PARTITION BY (OT.EXEC_BROKER) AS TRADED_AMT_WITH_CCP,
     COUNT(OT.TRADE_ID) OVER PARTITION BY (OT.EXEC_BROKER) AS TRADES_WITH_CCP

FROM dbo.ORDERS_TRADES OT

GROUP BY OT.TRADER_ID, OT.TRADER_NAME, OT.EXEC_BROKER, OT.TRADE_AMOUNT, OT.TRADE_ID
```

The code above runs but returns millions of rows. When I remove the partition by lines, I get the desired result minus the subtotal columns I'm looking for.

Any suggestions please? Thanks very much!

EDIT:

Final code which gave me the desired output: updating my question to provide this response (thanks to Gordon Linoff) so that others can benefit:

```
SELECT
         OT.TRADER_ID,
         OT.TRADER_NAME,
         OT.EXEC_BROKER,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY OT.TRADER_ID ORDER BY 
                SUM(OT.TRADE_AMOUNT) DESC) AS CCP_RANK,
         SUM(OT.TRADE_AMOUNT) AS TRADED_AMT_WITH_CCP,
         SUM(SUM(OT.TRADE_AMOUNT)) OVER (PARTITION BY OT.TRADER_ID) AS 
         VALUE_OF_TOTAL_TRADES,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY OT.TRADER_ID) AS NUM_OF_CCP_USED,
         SUM(COUNT(OT.TRADE_ID)) OVER (PARTITION BY OT.TRADER_ID) AS 
         TOTAL_TRADES
    
    FROM dbo.ORDERS_TRADES OT
    
    GROUP BY OT.TRADER_ID, OT.TRADER_NAME, OT.EXEC_BROKER
```

Comment: This question is difficult to follow because you keep switching terminology. For example, you talk about a "counterparty", but there's no "counterparty" column. You talk about a "subtotal", but there's no "subtotal" column. Your query refers to "trade_amount", but there's no "trade_amount" column. Your query refers to "exec_broker", but there's no "exec_broker" column.

Comment: Hi - apologies obviously did not mean to do that. CCP = Counterparty, also known as EXEC_BROKER. I actually never used the 'subtotal' terminology; I think this came about when my title was edited. The 'subtotals' I'm referring to are TRADES_WITH_CCP and TOTAL_TRADES in my desired output above. TRADE_AMOUNT is the same as TRADED_AMT, but I've fixed this in my question to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT OT.TRADER_ID, OT.TRADER_NAME, OT.CCP,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY OT.TRADER_ID) as NUM_CCP,
       SUM(OT.TRADED_AMT) AS TRADED_AMT_WITH_CCP,
       SUM(SUM(OT.TRADED_AMT)) OVER (PARTITION BY OT.TRADER_ID) AS VALUE_OF_TOTAL_TRADES,
       COUNT(OT.TRADE_ID) AS CCP_TRADES,
       SUM(COUNT(OT.TRADE_ID)) OVER (PARTITION BY OT.TRADER_ID) AS TOTAL_TRADES
FROM ORDERS_TRADES OT
GROUP BY OT.TRADER_ID, OT.TRADER_NAME, OT.CCP;
```

I'm not sure what your query has to do with the results you want.  The columns have little to do with what you are asking.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=86976c9b051f1828aaa82cd9a63a5d6a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Your code is perfect and I was able to adapt it to solve my problem - thanks very much! I also used RANK() to sort the final results in desc order by value of trades per counterparty. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about the nomenclature, here is a solution that doesn't use anything too fancy so it's easy to maintain, though it's not the most efficient:

```
create table trades
(
    TRADER_ID varchar(10), 
    TRADER_NAME varchar(20), 
    CCP char(4), 
    TRADED_AMT decimal(10,2), 
    TRADE_ID varchar(10) primary key
);

insert trades
values
    ('ABC123', 'Jules Winnfield', 'GOLD', 10000 , 'ASDADAD'),
    ('XDA241', 'Jimmie Dimmick ', 'GOLD', 12000 , 'ASSVASD'),
    ('ADC123', 'Vincent Vega   ', 'BARC', 10000 , 'ZXCZCX'),
    ('ABC123', 'Jules Winnfield', 'BARC', 15000 , 'ASSXCQA'),
    ('ADC123', 'Vincent Vega   ', 'CRED', 250000, 'RFAQQA'),
    ('ABC123', 'Jules Winnfield', 'CRED', 5000  , 'ASDQ23A'),
    ('ABC123', 'Jules Winnfield', 'GOLD', 5000  , 'AVBDQ3A');

with trader_totals as 
(
    select   trader_id,
             distinct_ccps = count(distinct CCP),
             total_amt = sum(traded_amt),
             total_count = count(*)
    from     trades
    group by trader_id
)
select      trader_id               = tr.trader_id,
            trader_name             = trader_name,
            distinct_CCP_count      = tt.distinct_ccps,
            CCP                     = tr.CCP,
            this_CCP_traded_amt     = sum(traded_amt),
            total_traded_amt        = tt.total_amt,
            this_CCP_traded_count   = count(*),
            total_traded_count      = tt.total_count

from        trades          tr
join        trader_totals   tt on tt.trader_id = tr.trader_id
group by    tr.trader_id,
            tr.trader_name,
            tr.CCP,
            tt.distinct_ccps,
            tt.total_amt,
            tt.total_count
```